# Error binding variable in dynamic PLSQL

Tags: data-binding, plsql, oracle10g, dynamic-sql

My sqlQuery is this:

```
sqlQuery := 'SELECT sa.nombre_archivo, sha.registrosok, sha.registroserroneos,'||
            ' sha.registrosinconsistentes,'||
            ' (sha.registrosok+sha.registroserroneos+sha.registrosinconsistentes),'||
            ' sha.fechaprocesamiento'||
              ' FROM src_historialarchivo sha, src_archivo sa, src_usuario su'||
            ' WHERE sa.idarchivo = sha.idarchivo'||
              ' AND sa.nombre_archivo LIKE ''%:1%'''||
              ' AND sa.idusuario = su.idusuario'||
              ' AND isvalidrange(sha.fechaprocesamiento,:2,:3) = ''T'''||
            ' ORDER BY to_date(sha.fechaprocesamiento, ''DD/MM/YYYY'')';
```

But there's seems to be a problem with the binding-variable `:1`, how to solve it?
The error thrown is `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01006`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
sqlQuery := 'SELECT sa.nombre_archivo, sha.registrosok, sha.registroserroneos,'||
            ' sha.registrosinconsistentes,'||
            ' (sha.registrosok+sha.registroserroneos+sha.registrosinconsistentes),'||
            ' sha.fechaprocesamiento'||
              ' FROM src_historialarchivo sha, src_archivo sa, src_usuario su'||
            ' WHERE sa.idarchivo = sha.idarchivo'||
              ' AND sa.nombre_archivo LIKE :1'||
              ' AND sa.idusuario = su.idusuario'||
              ' AND isvalidrange(sha.fechaprocesamiento,:2,:3) = ''T'''||
            ' ORDER BY to_date(sha.fechaprocesamiento, ''DD/MM/YYYY'')';

execute immediate sqlQuery using '%abc%';
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! ... Why do the binding variables aren't recognized if they are between quotes?